# Android Gps issue

Tags: android, gps

The following code works on some devices but it does not work other devices. If I check the gps setting the gps is on and provides a mock location. My manifest file also as the following permissions:

```
// Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider 
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);


        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: Google has introduced new way of getting location through google play services. Refer this : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/. This seems to be better way of getting location than previous methods. Just a suggestion, not really an answer to your question :)

Comment: @Abhishek I want only storing the details of latitude and longtitude position only... any idea do u know???